# How do I perform a page break when using "output: pdf_document:" in R markdown

Tags: r-markdown

I am trying to create page breaks using:

```
----
```

however if the output: pdf_document: option is set, all I get are horizontal rules.

Is there any fix to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could directly use Latex code in your .Rmd document. 
Simply replace `----` with `\newpage` and it should work.